# Disabling a Select Form Control in Reactive Forms/Angular 4+

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, disabled-control

I am trying to disable a select form control in my reactive form. Is there any issues with this currently? I have been looking around for an answer but I am unable to get a straight answer. The code I am using works fine if it is a regular input control, but not for a select control.

```
<select id="locationScanType" class="form-control" formControlName="locationScanType">                     
  <option value="0">-- Select One --</option>
  <option value="FACILITY">Facility</option>
  <option value="CUSTOMER_LOCATION">Customer Location</option>
  <option value="MY_LOCATION">My Location</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="textInput" />
```

In my `ngOnInit()` function I do this:

```
this.stopForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  locationScanType: { value: this.stop.locationScanType, disabled: true }, // Hard code true for demo
  textInput: { value: 'Text Input', disabled: true }
});
```

The `disabled` attribute works for the text input, but doesn't for the select input. It does select the correct value for the select input, but doesn't disable it. Am I missing something obvious?

I can disable the select input by using the `[attr.disabled]` and/or `[ngClass]` attributes on the select input, but I'd rather do it in the form builder; not to mention if I don't, Angular throws a warning into my browser's console.

`typescript: 2.4.2`

`@angular/core: 5.1.3`

`@angular/forms: 5.2.0`

Comment: Is there anywhere in your code that you are enabling the select programmatically?

Comment: No, there isn't. The only thing that allows it to be enabled is if it is a certain type of "stop", but I made sure that this code works as intended, and it does.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the disable function that provide the FormControl class. once you have the form created you can call this function in the specific form control

```
this.stopForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  locationScanType: { value: this.stop.locationScanType }, // Hard code true for demo
  textInput: { value: 'Text Input', disabled: true }
});

this.stopForm.get("locationScanType").disable()
```

Comment: I'm with the same issue

Comment: I want set null for value and disable. How to do it? I used `` this.form.patchvalue({ dropDown: [{value: null , disbaled: true}] }); ``  But it doesnt disable but value set null. Any idea